# any_of Versus find_if

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, find

C++11 introduced `any_of` to `algorithm`s.

This seems to work exactly like `find_if`.

Say I have a functor: `function<bool(int)> foo;`
And an array: `vector<int> bar;`

It seems like these two calls do the exact same thing:

```
any_of(bar.begin(), bar.end(), foo);
```

and

```
bar.end() != find_if(bar.begin(), bar.end(), foo);
```

I further feel that `all_of`, and `none_of` can be accomplished by negating the `find_if` statement.

**Are these algorithms just here to do the comparison to `end` for us, or is there a usefulness I don't understand?**

Comment: You're right. GCC's library implements all_of / none_of / any_of as calls to last==find_if_not / last==find_if / !none_of respectively

Comment: @JonathanWakely Can you put that in an answer? I would like to accept that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe you're right that they are just more convenient interfaces to functionality that can be achieved in other ways.

The proposal to add them to the standard ([N2666](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2666.pdf)) says:

> These three algorithms provide the ordinary mathematical operations ∀, ∃, and ∄: given a
>   range and a predicate, determine whether that predicate is true for all elements; whether
>   there exists an element for which the predicate is true; or whether there exist no elements
>   for which the predicate is true. Strictly speaking there is no need to provide all three of
>   these algorithms (`!none_of` and `any_of` are equivalent), but all three of these operations
>   feel equally fundamental.

The names are more natural and easier to read (certainly for non-expert C++ programmers) than an expression involving `find_if` and an (in)equality.

GCC's standard library implements them by simply calling other functions:

`all_of(first, last, pred)` is `return last == std::find_if_not(first, last, pred);`

`none_of(first, last, pred)` is `return last == std::find_if(first, last, pred);`

`any_of(first, last, pred)` is `return !none_of(first, last, pred);`

Answer (score 8):

Please note the return type of the two algorithms. Just like `binary_search` only returns if the provided element can be found in a sorted sequence, while `lower_bound` returns an iterator to first element not smaller than the provided element,`any_of` and `find_if` complement each other. Note that `binary_search` is (almost) the same as `!(val < lower_bound(a.begin(), a.end(), val))`

`any_of` will only tell you **if** the predicate holds for any element, while `find_if` will return an iterator to the element that makes the predicate become true. Also note that `find_if` guarantees that an iterator to the **first** element that makes the predicate become true will be returned, while `any_of` does not have such restrictions. Thus in theory in some cases `any_of` can be more efficient.

Comment: I don't think you've really addressed the core question - is `any_of` just a shorthand for `find_if(:::) != end()`? You're touching on the subject with the last sentence about efficiency, but I think this would deserve more than a passing comment.

Comment: @remyabel I think that the statement was just that, "`any_of` *can* be more efficient." That is to say there's no need to maintain or return an iterator in `any_of` so *if* there was a quicker algorithm than linearly comparing each element that could be used for `any_of`.

Comment: @Angew that is your opinion. I do not have a definite answer on the question and that is why I propose several possible explanations: 1) For consistency(there are other similar examples in the standard) 2) for efficiency(any_of **can** be more efficient) 3) ease of use - `any_if` is boolean while `find_if` is not therefor if we only care of the existence of elements matching the predicate we can use `any_of`. I do not agree that out of these the efficiency is most important and further I doubt that any of the common implementations is really more efficient for `any_of`

Comment: Efficiency can indeed improve, if the search is executed in parallel on multiple cores